# How to flatten an image?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

How do you flatten an image?

I know that we make use conv2d and pooling to detect the edges and minimize the size of the picture, so do we then flatten it after that?

Will the flattened, pooled image will be a vector in one row and features or one column and the features?

Do we make the equation x_data=x_date/255 after flattening or before convolution and pooling?

I hope to know the answer.

Comment: Hello and welcome. It's really hard to understand your question, if possible at all.

Comment: I mean flatten will be after or before conv2d and pooling ? And it will be a vector in one row and features or one column and the features?

Comment: This question using a python tag but I can't see any python on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the pipeline:

Input image (could be in batches - let's say your network processes 10 images simultaneously) so 10 images of size (28, 28) -- 28 pixels height / weight and let's say the image has 1 filter only (grayscale).

You are supposed to provide to your network an input of size (10, 28, 28, 1), which will be accepted by a convolutional layer. You are free to use max pooling and maybe an activation function. Your convolutional layer will apply a number of filters of your choice -- let's assume you want to apply 40 filters. These are 40 different kernels applied with different weights. If you want to let's say classify these images you will (most likely) have a number of Dense layers after your convolutional layers. Before passing the output of the convolutional layers (which will be a representation of your input image after a feature extraction process) to your dense layers you have to flatten it in a way (You may use the simplest form of flattening, just passing the numbers one after the other). So your dense layer accepts the output of these 40 filters, which will be 'images' -- their size depends on many things (kernel size, stride, original image size) which will later be flattened into a vector, which supposedly propagates forward the information extracted by your conv layer.

Your second question regarding MinMaxScaling (div by 255) - That is supposed to take place before everything else. There are other ways of normalizing your data (Standar scaling -- converting to 0 mean and unit variance) but keep in mind, when using transformations like that, you are supposed to fit the transformation on your train data and transform your test data accordingly. You are not supposed to fit and transform on your test data. Here, dividing by 255 everything is accepted but keep that in mind for the future.